# Trying to Understand Why Insert Mysql Returns False & How to Fix

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand why my Insert is returning false w/ no results found.

```
$mysql_link=mysqli_connect(host,user,dbpswd,dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();} // Never shows
mysqli_set_charset($mysql_link,"utf8");
...
echo $TableName; // Outputs correct table name
echo $flds; // Outputs correct field names, didn't include id field, as auto generated
field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8@2x, field9, field10, field11

echo $str; // Outputs correct field values, didn't include id value
'***', '0', '0.0', '2018-07-28', '16:42:00', '0.00', 'you@yoursite.com', '***', '../rw_common/plugins/stacks/myimage.png', 'https://www.google.com', '***'

$query="INSERT INTO ".$TableName."(".$flds.") VALUES (".$str.")";
$mysql_result = mysqli_query($mysql_link,$query);

if ($mysql_result->num_rows > 0) {echo 'record found';}
else {echo 'query ok but no results found';} // Outputs this line !
if ($mysql_result===false) // Resolves to false
```

Is there anything else I can check and how to fix this?

Update1:

```
echo $query: Outputs this:
INSERT INTO mytable3(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8@2x, field9, field10, field11) VALUES ('***', '0', '0.0', '2018-07-28', '16:55:00', '0.00', 'you@yoursite.com', '***', '../rw_common/plugins/stacks/myimage.png', 'https://www.google.com', '***')
```

Update2:

```
echo $query:
INSERT INTO mytable3(`field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`, `field5`, `field6`, `field7`, `field8@2x`, `field9`, `field10`, `field11`) VALUES ('***', '0', '0.0', '2018-07-28', '17:15:00', '0.00', 'you@yoursite.com', '***', '../rw_common/plugins/stacks/myimage.png', 'https://www.google.com', '***')
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](//stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: @FrankerZ  I realize it could be, but fields & values are auto-generated, i.e. no direct input

Comment: `echo $query;` and run it in phpmyadmin (or directly on the database). Also, isn't it `$mysqli_result->num_rows()`?

Comment: Even if there is no direct input, you should still avoid it when you have so many functions to bind variables to the query. No reason to be sloppy. What if something gets auto-generated with a quote, and it breaks your query?

Comment: @FrankerZ  When I added () got PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean?  & see $query update above.

Comment: I was wrong about that, but you should still `echo $query;` and run it

Comment: @FrankerZ  See Update 1

Comment: Check for errors on the execution http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php.

Comment: `if (!$mysql_result) { echo mysqli_error($mysql_link); }`. My guess is it has something to do with `field8@2x`.

Comment: Also what are your actual column names. If any are reserved or contain special characters they need to be encapsulated in backticks.

Comment: Have you checked the data types? You save those data as varchar/text in the db?

Comment: Ah, you are right @FrankerZ the `@` is outside the accepted character range "basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore".

Comment: And look out about thw field8@2x. It probably needs ' or something. If you want to see more info,try to execute the query directy on the db

Comment: Pleassssse use the error reporting. It will tell you the exact issue.

Comment: Using @FrankerZ error check - I discovered that there was a field in the db that I wasn't accounting for - duh !  But as usual, a learning experience ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for those who might have a similar problem:  You need to wrap the fields in back ticks to account for someone using special characters or reserved names.  Also, I discovered a field that was not being entered, which was also breaking the insert ;)

Answer (score 0):

There was a forgotten field that showed up when the query examined and compared w/ the database - mismatch was causing the error.